# AngularJS directive not showing the element appended in link function

Tags: angularjs

**HTML:**

```
<div class="test">
  <percentage-bar progress-array="slaInfo" progress-x-max="100" progress-y-max="100">
   </percentage-bar>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
.directive("percentageBar", function ($compile) {
            function link(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
                // elem.empty()
                elem = angular.element("<div />").attr("class", "percentageBarBox");
                var left = angular.element("<div />").attr("class", "percentageLeft").attr("ng-style", "leftStyle");
                var middle = angular.element("<div />").attr("class", "percentageMiddle").attr("ng-style", "middleStyle");
                var right = angular.element("<div />").attr("class", "percentageRight").attr("ng-style", "rightStyle");
                elem.append($compile(left)(scope));
                elem.append($compile(middle)(scope));
                elem.append($compile(right)(scope));
                console.log(elem);// I can see the result printed in the chrome devtool, it's correct.
            }

            return {
                restrict: "AE",
                scope: {
                    progressArray: "=",
                    progressXMax: "@",
                    progressYMax: "@",
                },
                controller: function ($scope) {
                    $scope.leftStyle = {
                        'height': $scope.progressArray[0].y / $scope.progressYMax * 100 + '%',
                        'width': $scope.progressArray[0].x / $scope.progressXMax * 100 + '%'
                    };
                    $scope.middleStyle = {
                        'height': $scope.progressArray[1].y / $scope.progressYMax * 100 + '%',
                        'width': $scope.progressArray[1].x / $scope.progressXMax * 100 + '%'
                    };
                    $scope.rightStyle = {
                        'height': $scope.progressArray[2].y / $scope.progressYMax * 100 + '%',
                        'width': $scope.progressArray[2].x / $scope.progressXMax * 100 + '%'
                    };
                },
                link: link
            };
        });
```

Pls have a look at the last sentence of link function, i can see the result printed in console of chrome devtool, and the result is right. But I can't see the dom element in the Elements pane of chrome devtool.

**Result:**

```
<div class="test">
    <percentage-bar progress-array="slaInfo" progress-x-max="100" progress-y-max="100" class="ng-isolate-scope">
    </percentage-bar>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you should, first of all, convert your `link` function to a `compile` one. Then you drop the usage of `$compile` :)

Comment: Don't build templates by hand. Directives have a template property...

Comment: In my case, the number of element is fixed, so i use a template to do the job. If the element is dynamic, @gustavohenke's suggestion maybe a good a solution, thanks very much. :)